# Shower or place to change clothes at this beach in Ibiza?

Tags: spain

Our flight from Ibiza is scheduled after midnight and I want to spend it on a beach. I found that there is a nice beach with clubs close to an airport: 38.878339, 1.403609. There are some clubs like Coco beach, Nassau, Beach house or Club Bahamas. Is there a possibility to take a shower and change clothes in any of these restaurants or at the beach?

Comment: If you stay in a hotel at Ibiza, would it be possible to leave your luggage there and use one of their showers/rooms to change at the end of the day or is that a long distance from the airport?

Comment: No, we will be at AirBnB.

Comment: Are there no showers on the beach itself?

Comment: I do not know, I have never been there.

Answer (score 3):

The location you specifify is [Playa d'en Bossa Beach](http://www.ibiza-spotlight.com/beach/playa_den_bossa_i.htm). From the site:

Facilities: Loungers, parasols, **showers**, lifeguards, lockers, access for the disabled, restaurants, bars, shops

Showers are also listed on this [alternate](https://www.ibizaintro.com/guides/beaches/playa-den-bossa-beach) site.

Other Ibiza beaches also list showers as a facility.

Also nearby is [Aguamar water park](http://www.ibiza-spotlight.com/activity/aguamar) which has an entry fee of €18 and closes at 6pm though I doubt this will be of interest to you.

Alternatively, you *may* be able to visit one of the neaby hotels such as the [Hard Rock Hotel](http://www.hrhibiza.com/) as a day visitor, perhaps just for the price of a drink and take a shower at the pool.

Comment: Have anybody been there to confirm their website information?

Comment: Should be something like this: https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-child-using-beach-shower-on-platja-d-en-bossa-beach-in-ibiza-spain-3433631.html